# If an animal eats chometz on Pesach of its own accord, is its owner guilty of benefitting from Chometz?

Tags: passover

One may not feed Chometz to his animal on Pesach, since chometz is "OSSUR B"HANAH" (forbidden to derive benefit thereof).

If an animal eats cometz on Pesach of its own accord, is its owner guilty of benefitting from Chometz?

Is there a difference f the owner stands by and allows it to eat, or if he is unaware of the animal eating chometz.

Even if the owner is unaware of the animal eating chometz, would this be considered benefitting from the chometz בשוגג (unintentionally)? If not, why not?